# Hide div when clicking link

Tags: html, css

I have two divs, side by side. When I click the link in div 2, I need outer-div 1 to hide. I need this to work without javascript. And I have done it before, but that same code no longer works.

I am using the following code:

```
<a href="#" name="trigger">Click Me</a>
<hr />
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
```

---

```
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}

.foo {
    background: red;
}

.bar {
    background: blue;
}

a:active ~ .foo {
    display: none;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spikey/826CU/)

to hide a div when a link in another div has been clicked. It used to work but no longer works. Why isn't this working anymore?

I am using Chrome (latest stable) and IE 11.

Comment: http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-showhide

Comment: Thanks @dcc so that page uses a checkbox. Does this mean I have to use a checkbox too? I mean, I only think that because they styled it to look like a button. Why is this so hard now? You used to be able to just do `.whatever:active ~ .jellybean {}`, right?

Comment: @Spike Nothing that changed. In your particular example, `#trigger:active ~ foo` works, but only as long as you depress the mouse button. The problem is that with a link, you are submitting the page when you release the button. One possible solution would be to use a non-submitting button, which can be focused. http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/826CU/5/

Comment: But you'd be better off using a hidden checkbox, and a label for the checkbox that you can use to click on. You can style the label to look like a link. http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/826CU/6/

Comment: Try using :target (answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this, using `:target` selector.

HTML

```
<a href="#bar" name="trigger">Click Me</a>
<hr />
<div id="foo"></div>
<div id="bar"></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}

#foo {
    background: red;
}

#bar {
    background: blue;
}

:target {
 display: none;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/826CU/7/

Comment: hey, that's really cool. And it works! I have one question though, how what is target? How does it know which div I want to hide? And how does it know which link I clicked?

Comment: It used the href="#bar" to know which to target.

Comment: Thanks! I just googled it too and CSS Tricks said the same. +1

Comment: Here is docs about :target http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.asp Target div is defined by href atribute in your "Click me" link. Divs you want to be hidden must have ID's.

Answer (score 1):

The only action you can use for click would be :active however, this is only for the mousedown.  When you release the click it will return to normal.  Why can you not use javascript?  That would be optimal in this circumstance.

Then you could just toggle a class with an opacity of 0 to either div.

```
.one {
        background: white;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
    }
    .one:hover {
        height: 100px;
    }
    .two {
        position:absolute;
        top: 50px;
        background:white;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
    }
    .two:hover {
        top: 0;
        height:100px;
    }
    .one:hover + .two {
        z-index: -1; 
    }
```

Comment: I cannot use JavaScript because many of our customers are um. I won't say what I'm thinking, but they just won't or can't have JavaScript enabled. I'm pretty tolerant when it comes to these things but it's 2014 ffs, either enable javascript or f-off.

Comment: Ok, I gotcha.  Um, more than likely you'd need to do something hacky like the guy before me posted.  Best of luck.  You could use a hover to widen the div to where it covered the other div, but again, this is contrived and probably isn't worth the trouble.

Comment: Thanks Ty, I am still looking at dcc's code. It looks like it's what I want, but I have a ul with a few li's and I really don't wanna make them all checkboxes (unless i'm mistaken).

Answer (score 1):

One other method without using javascript would be:

HTML:

```
<div class="collapse" tabindex="1">
     <h2 >Collapse 1 +</h2>
     <p>Content 1....</p>
  </div>

    <div class="collapse" tabindex="1">
     <h2 >Collapse 2 +</h2>
     <p>Content 2....</p>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.collapse > * + *{
  display:none;
}
.collapse > *{
  cursor:pointer;
}
.collapse:focus{
  outline:none;
}
.collapse:focus > * + *{
  display:block; 
}
```

See if this helps.
[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DtPtD/)

Answer (score 1):

```
  #foo {
    display:none;
  }
  #foo:target {
    display:block;
  }


<a href="#foo">Click</a>
<div id="foo">to display me</div>
```

The pseudo-class :target is used to style the target element of a URI containing a fragment identifier.